# Need help in manipulating rational absolute value inequalities.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

How does one manipulate rational absolute inequalities?

For example, I want to transform the absolute value inequality $$|x-3|<1,$$ to $$\frac{|x+3|}{5x^2}<A,$$ for some number A, and using $$|x-3|<1$$ as a constraint or starting point, and to find an upper and lower bound on the latter term and not sure what to do with the denominator and changing inequality direction.

I can expand the absolute value inequality as follows: $$|x-3|<1 \implies -1<x-3<1 \implies 2<x<4 \implies 5<x+3<7. $$ How do I introduce the $5x^2$ term in the denominator? Dividing all three sides by $5x^2$ would add a variable to the numbers and possibly change signs. Not sure where to go from here.

For context, this question is not for homework but in reference to bounding terms for epsilon-delta limit proofs. I know you can bound the numerator and denominator separately but I really would like to know how manipulate the quotient together as I have forgotten some elementary algebra.

Thanks!

Edit:  More info: If $$|x-3|<1, $$ then $$|x-3|<1 \implies -1<x-3<1 \implies 2<x<4 \implies 5<x+3<7$$ for the numerator and $$\frac{1}{4}<\frac{1}{x}<\frac{1}{2} \implies \frac{1}{16}<\frac{1}{x^2}<\frac{1}{4} \implies \frac{1}{80}<\frac{1}{5x^2}<\frac{1}{20}$$ for the denominator.

Dividing produces $$\frac{5}{80}<\frac{x+3}{5x^2}<\frac{7}{20} \implies -\frac{7}{20}<\frac{5}{80}<\frac{x+3}{5x^2}<\frac{7}{20} \implies \frac{|x+3|}{5x^2}<\frac{7}{20}.$$

The questions I have are (a) can the numerator and denominator be separated and recombined as above? If not, how to I transform $$|x-3|<1$$ to $$\frac{|x+3|}{5x^2}<\frac{7}{20}$$ without splitting the fraction?

Does that help?

Comment: "*I want to transform the inequality ____ to ____*"  What do you mean by this?  In what way are these two inequalities related?  They do not have the same solution set which should hopefully be clear and obvious.  For instance, if I plug a million into the first inequality it does not hold but if I plug a million into the second inequality it does hold...

Comment: I made a mistake in the original post and corrected. I want to use bound $$\frac{|x+3|}{5x^2}<A$$ using $$|x-3|<1.$$ Does that make more sense?

Comment: @bamajon1974 You found that $x \in [2,4]$ so what's left to do is find some bounds for $\frac{|x+3|}{5x^2}$ on $[2,4]$.

Comment: I edited the original post to find the upper bounds.

Comment: @bamajon1974 That works. Or, use that $f(x) = \frac{x+3}{5x^2}=\frac{1}{5x}+\frac{3}{5x^2}$ is positive and decreasing for $x \in [2,4]$ so $f(x) \le f(2)=\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Ah, so you are splitting up the quotient and using the triangle inequality theorem to find the bounds?

Comment: @bamajon1974 You should use an `@name` for the other user to be notified of your reply. There is no triangle inequality needed here, since you are working on the interval $x \in [2,4]$ where all terms are positive, so $|x+3|=x+3$.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to résove this inequality is to to study the function f(x)=|x+3|/(5x²) for x in  [2,4] you find that  0<x<1/20enter image description here

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I made a mistake in the original post and corrected. I want to use bound $$\frac{|x+3|}{5x^2}<A$$ using $$|x-3|<1.$$ Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

A=1/20=0.05
I find this easly by drawing the function f(x)=|x+3|/5x² for |x−3|<1. ie 2<x<4.
by using geogebra for x in[2,4], i find 0<f(x)<0.05. i can't post the picture. but it is easy  to draw this by geogebra  use : (2<x<4, f(x)=|x+3|/5x²) in online geogebra.

it obvious tha the min of numerator is 4 and the max of denomenator is 5*4²=80
so the max of the fraction is A=4/80=0.05

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The minimum of numerator is 4
The maximum of denominator is 8o
Hence the fraction is less then 4/80=1/20 so we can take A=1/20